# How to convert dataframe to RDD and store it in cassandra using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

How to convert dataframe to RDD and store it in Cassandra in Spark Scala.
Consider an example like below,

```
emp_id| emp_city|emp_name

 1|Hyderabad| ram
 4| Banglore| deeksha
```

Here I am using only 3 columns as an example but I need to deal with 18 columns actually.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly save DF without converting into RDD.

```
df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map( "table" -> "employee", "keyspace" -> "emp_data")).save()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi,Thanks , i had tried this option it is working fine with simple tables like above, but i have few timestamp columns and null values and all. when i try to use this option ,its giving error saying like  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Invalid row size: 18 instead of 17.

Comment: Hi, please find the below link for more details about the question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/51929246/10246547