# How to use properties in spark scala maven project

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

i want to include properties file explicitly and include it in spark code , instead of hardcoding directly in spark code with all credentials.
i am trying following approach but not able to do, AppContext is not able to be resolved.
please guide me how to achieve this.

### Spark_env.properties (under src/main/resourcses in maven project for spark with scala)

```
CASSANDRA_HOST1=127.0.0.133
CASSANDRA_PORT1=9042
CASSANDRA_USER1=usr1
CASSANDRA_PASS1=pas2



DataMigration.cassandra.keyspace1=demo2
DataMigration.cassandra.table1= data1

CASSANDRA_HOST2= 
CASSANDRA_PORT2=9042
CASSANDRA_USER2=usr2
CASSANDRA_PASS2=pas2

D.cassandra.keyspace2=kesp2
D.cassandra.table2= data2

DataMigration.DifferencedRecords.output.path1=C:/spark_windows_proj/File1.csv
DataMigration.DifferencedRecords.output.path2=C:/spark_windows_proj/File1.parquet

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DM.scala

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.AppContext

object Data_Migration {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {



    val host1: String = AppContext.getProperties().getProperty("CASSANDRA_HOST1")
    val port1 = AppContext.getProperties().getProperty("CASSANDRA_PORT1").toInt
    val keySpace1: String = AppContext.getProperties().getProperty("DataMigration.cassandra.keyspace1")
    val DataMigrationTableName1: String = AppContext.getProperties().getProperty("DataMigration.cassandra.table1")
    val username1: String = AppContext.getProperties().getProperty("CASSANDRA_USER1")
    val pass1: String = AppContext.getProperties().getProperty("CASSANDRA_PASS1")

     val host2: String = AppContext.getProperties().getProperty("CASSANDRA_HOST2")
       val port2 = AppContext.getProperties().getProperty("CASSANDRA_PORT2").toInt
    val keySpace2: String = AppContext.getProperties().getProperty("DataMigration.cassandra.keyspace2")
    val DataMigrationTableName2: String = AppContext.getProperties().getProperty("DataMigration.cassandra.table2")
    val username2: String = AppContext.getProperties().getProperty("CASSANDRA_USER2")
    val pass2: String = AppContext.getProperties().getProperty("CASSANDRA_PASS2")




     val Result_csv: String = AppContext.getProperties().getProperty("DataMigration.DifferencedRecords.output.path1")
      val Result_parquet: String = AppContext.getProperties().getProperty("DataMigration.DifferencedRecords.output.path2")



    val sc = AppContext.getSparkContext()


    val spark = SparkSession
                      .builder() .master("local")
                      .appName("ABC")
                      .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
                      .getOrCreate()



    val df_read1 = spark.read
                       .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                       .option("spark.cassandra.connection.host",host1)
                       .option("spark.cassandra.connection.port",port1)
                       .option( "spark.cassandra.auth.username",username1)
                       .option("spark.cassandra.auth.password",pass1)
                       .option("keyspace",keySpace1)
                       .option("table",DataMigrationTableName1)
                       .load()
```

Comment: Have you tried using Typesafe config ?

Comment: Thanks..i will check about that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather pass the properties explicitly by passing the `--properties-file` option to the `spark-submit` when submitting the job.

The AppContext won't necessary work for all submission types, while passing config file should work everywhere.

Edit: For local usage without spark-submit, you can simply use the standard `Properties` class, loading it from the resources and get access to properties. You only need to put property file into `src/main/resources` instead of `src/test/resources` that is included into classpath only for tests. The code is something like:

```
val props = new Properties
props.load(getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("file.props"))
```